'Open in Terminal' opens terminal in home directory only from whichever folder I open it. [Ubuntu 24.04]
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04. Yesterday, the last two commands I executed were sudo apt-get clean and sudo apt-get autoclean, as I remember. After this, I observed that from whichever folder I open the terminal using 'Open in Terminal', the terminal opens in the home directory path. Ideally, opening terminal from file manager should open with the respective path from where the terminal is opened. I can not find out how to correct it. Please help.

Question is unclear as to did it work before you ran the two commands?

It was working absolutely fine few moments ago. I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. Perhaps I have executed any systems file (inadvertently) that has overwritten the opening drive path for terminal. I am inviting a pro in Linux who knows how to correct the $PATH entry for default terminal drive path and which file to correct the entry.
